# WordPress URL with anchor tag resolving to 404

Tags: php, html, wordpress, anchor

I have a bizarre issue with WordPress wherein I have an anchor tag on my about page like this:

`<h2><a id="comments">Why No Comments?</a></h2>`

and when I link to it in my footer like this:

`<a href="<?php echo home_url()?>/about/#comments">Why no comments?</a>`

it inexplicably resolves to `http://www.everydaytype.com/omments`.

What could be going on here?

Note: The same thing happens when I navigate to the URL of the anchor tag manually.

(Reference: [everydaytype.com](http://everydaytype.com))

**UPDATE:** I have disabled all of my plug-ins (I have one that manipulates a link in my header), and this is still occurring.

Comment: You have a redirect within your wordpress.

Comment: Your link is fine `<a href="http://www.everydaytype.com/about/#comments">Why no comments?</a>` but then you have a redirect

Comment: Right, but how would I resolve that? And where is the redirect coming from if not from any plug-ins?

Comment: You need to identify where your redirect comes from. What is `about` supposed to be?

Comment: `/about` is my about page. Going to `<a href="http://www.everydaytype.com/about">` works. It's only when the anchor is added that there's a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty bizarre thing for a site to do.

If you load the url `http://www.everydaytype.com/about/#comments` into a View Source window in your browser, you'll find that it contains the following code:

```
<script>if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var hashtourl = hash.substring(2)
    window.location.href = "/"+hashtourl;
}</script>
```

This code does exactly what you're describing.

I have no idea why it would do that, but that's what it's doing.

My guess is that it's expecting a `#!` rather than just a `#`, hence the dropping of the first two characters rather than just the first, but that's just a guess. And if that is what it's expecting, it really ought to be checking for it rather than making an assumption.

I guess it must be part of some plugin that you don't know about or thought you'd disabled haven't fully, or something. Either way, having the code above to hand should help you locate it.

That's all I can do to help, but I hope it gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Yep. That was some errant code in `header.php` from the theme I was using. Thanks so much.